# How do I publicly share a folder in Owncloud 4.5?

Tags: owncloud

I want to create a *public folder* (like [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com/)) in my [owncloud](http://owncloud.org/) installation where I can put files that others can access without having to create an account.

*Is this possible with owncloud 4.5.x?*

Comment: Perhaps you can add info to the wiki tag?

Comment: This is self-hosted, no? We don't really support those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple though, just do the following:

1. Login to your owncloud account at your server
2. Navigate your mouse to the folder that you wanted to share
3. You will see that *Rename*, *Share* and *Download* will appear
   [image: Navigate your mouse to the folder that you wanted to share]
4. Tick **Share with Link** and share that link with anyone that you want to or you can use the mailing feature to email the link to those who you want.
   [image: Tick Share with Link and copy the link]